# what is the difference between '1' - 0 and '1' - '0'

Tags: java, ascii

I know that `'1' - '0'` is based on ASCII value.
But for `'1' - 0`, how is `'1'` becoming an integer automatically instead of its ASCII value?

Comment: check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: I guess that's called "widening primitive conversion", see [JLS § 5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).